# Get image metadata from MediaWiki image page

Tags: mediawiki

I would like to retrieve metadata beyond the technical metadata associated with an image (thus not the EXIF data, size, versions, etc) by which I mean the "non-technical" metadata e.g. image title (not filename),   description, artists/creator (not uploader), creation date (of work, not file), etc.

For example the items listed under "summary" in [this File page](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:The_Nightwatch_by_Rembrandt.jpg).

Is that information accessible via the API or is it considered human created page content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is available on wikis using the [CommonsMetadata extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CommonsMetadata) if users took care to start using it. Commons should have this information for most images, see the extension page for API examples.